# How can I populate a Dictionary from appsettings.json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this class

```
public class MySettings
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> MyDictionary;
}
```

and this appsettings.json file

```
{
  "MySettings": {
    one: "two",
    three: "four"
  }
}
```

But the dictionary is not populated on app start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dictionary has to be a property, so try changing it to this

```
public Dictionary<string, string> MyDictionary { get; set; }
```